# PHP Mysql database copy

Tags: mysqli

```
   db1                              db2
  table1                          table2
```

I want to copy db1.table1 from db2.table2 on php

connect function :

```
function baglan()

{
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', '111', '111', 'db1')or die("error");  
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
return $mysqli;
}
```

php my sql query :

```
query="Insert Into `db1`.`table1` 
Select *  From `db2`.`table2`; ";
```

run query :

```
baglan()->query($query);
```

This is working on phpmyadmin but this is not working on php

Comment: You don't appear to be checking your call to `mysqli->query()` for errors. Do so and post the result.

Comment: $mysqli->select_db("db2"); ?

Comment: ` $conn = baglan();
    $conn->select_db("arsiv",true);
$conn->query($query);   `  Warning: mysqli::select_db() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in

Answer (score -1):

This is a very fast way to copy table2 to a new table1
If anyone can show a more efficient method, I'd like to see it.

I tested this method against the other common methods posted here and found this to be the best.  I have been using this for years to give each user their own table to edit.

```
mysqli_query("CREATE TABLE `db1`.`table1`  LIKE `db2`.`table2`");
mysqli_query("ALTER TABLE `db1`.`table1`  DISABLE KEYS");
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `db1`.`table1`  SELECT * FROM `db2`.`table2`");
mysqli_query("ALTER TABLE `db1`.`table1`  ENABLE KEYS");
```

I benchmarked this on a table of 5500 records.

- Create time 5 mS
- Disable Keys 0.2 mS
- Inset 5500 records 30 mS
- Enable Keys 36 mS

**About 70 milliseconds total** to create, inset 5500 records, and re-index.